# In Google Cloud's Logs Explorer, how do you query for a key's existence in the jsonPayload dict?

Tags: google-cloud-logging

In Google's Cloud Logging query language, is it possible to query for the existence of a particular key in the `jsonPayload` dict?

E.g., suppose I know the `jsonPayload` will either be

```
{'keyA':'<some string>'}
```

or

```
{'keyB':'<some string'}
```

But I don't know what the `<some string>` will be. I want all logs that have the `keyB` key. I suppose I could test that for that key having a regex that includes everything, but is that the best/only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "has" operator with a *, like

`jsonPayload.keyB:*`

See the end of https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#comparisons

Answer (score 2):

> I want all logs that have the keyB key. I suppose I could test that for that key having a regex that includes everything, but is that the best/only way?

I could think of using [Regex](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/cloud-logging-gets-regular-expression-support) for this use case:

Example:

```
jsonPayload.message =~"Job status: *"
```

In your case `keyB`

```
jsonPayload.keyB =~"regex-query"
```

For my example, when the expression matches, getting output as below:

[image]